# python-excel mismatch on defaults

Tags: python, excel

Python and Excel have a different behaviour for defaults. Python is passing optional arguments by keyword, while Excel is only positional, even on defaults. As a result, an unused argument is in reality passed, as None. Assuming as example the scipy function brentq:

```
brentq(f, a, b, xtol=1e-12, rtol=4.4408920985006262e-16,  maxiter=100, full_output=False, disp=True, *args)
```

calling it from Excel with xtol and rtol unset:

```
brentq(f,a,f,,,50)
```

will in reality be seen as

```
brentq(f,a,f,None,None,50)
```

and of course Python will not like None for xtol,rtol.
As an escamotage, till now, I have a function checking for default values:

```
def checkvals(f, args):
    a = inspect.getargspec(f)   
    defs = zip(a.args[-len(a.defaults):], a.defaults)
    for x in defs:
        key = x[0]
        if args[key] == None:
            args[key] = x[1]
    return args
```

and I wrap brentq as follows:

```
def brentq(f, a, b, xtol=1e-12, rtol=4.4408920985006262e-16,  maxiter=100, full_output=False, disp=True, *args):    
    x = checkvals(brentq, locals())
    return scipy.optimize.brentq (f, a, b, *args, x['xtol'], x['rtol'], x['maxiter'], x['full_output'], x['disp'])
```

It works, meaning that x['xtol'] and x['rtol'] are restored to their defaults. However, I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.
In other words: is it possible to modify locals() inside a function, and force the function to use the modified values?

Comment: This needs to be much clearer--this isn't about a "Python/Excel mismatch," it's about how Python handles default arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Excel passes `None` when you skip an argument, then put that in your Python function signature *as the default argument*. In fact, this is *the* Pythonic way to do it (for various reasons including default-argument mutability that aren't worth getting into here).

```
brentq(f, a, b, xtol=None, rtol=None,  maxiter=100, full_output=None, disp=None, *args):
    if xtol is None: xtol = 1e-12
    if rtol is None: rtol = 4.4408920985006262e-16
    if full_output is None: full_output = False
    if disp is None: disp = true
    # ... rest of function
```

Comment: You're right, but I'm trying to automate the excel-python interfacing: imagine to have to do the manual approach for all the scipy functions... .

Comment: @maurizio Ah, I missed that these are SciPy functions. I assume this is using xlwings?

Comment: No, I'm using xlloop: an excel .xll that acts as a client different servers, among which python.

Comment: @maurizionardò Hmmmm. Then it's probably an xlloop bug or simply a missing feature. My guess is that the Java version works and that the Python version is based on the Java version.

Comment: In any case, writing wrappers around the SciPy functions is probably your only option. Note that comparisons to `None` should be done with `is` rather than `==`. Other than that, your original solution actually isn't bad. There may be another approach using `args*` or, if VBA/xlloop supports it somehow, `kwargs**`.

Comment: Note also that once you're in Python code, skipping optional arguments should work as expected. So you shouldn't need to specify the same default args in your wrapper method(s) as are present in the SciPy signature; simply *don't pass* any args that are `None`. The "splat" operator will be helpful: construct a dictionary of named arguments and "splat" it into the SciPy call.

Comment: Thanx for your suggestions, Kyle, I will check about splat. Just to make things clearer, i'd add that VBA is not involved, the client is the C Excel api. Further, final unset optional arguments (say full_output, disp, args) are NOT passed, which is ok,  So, I think I would call this fully and only positional.

Answer (score 0):

I'm satisfied with final Kyle's suggestion. Following it the excel-python interface would be like (example tried in spyder):

```
import scipy.optimize

def f(x): 
    return -2*x**4 + 2*x**3 + -16*x**2 + -60*x + 100

#this is the wrapper for Excel  
def brentqWrapper (f, a, b, xtol=None, rtol=None, maxiter=None, full_output=None, disp=None,*args):
    return scipy.optimize.brentq (**{k: v for k, v in locals().items() if v!=None})

#this simulates the excel call with unset inner optional parameters:
print brentqWrapper(f,0,2,None,None,50)
>> 1.24078711375
```